# Getting two substrings/groups before and after last nth "_"

Tags: regex, r

Let's look at an example:

```
abc_def_ghi_jkl
```

If I choose `n = 1`, I want the output to be:

```
group1 = abc_def_ghi
group2 = jkl
```

If I choose `n = 2`, I want the output to be:

```
group1 = abc_def
group2 = ghi_jkl
```

**Note:** The `_` that separated the two groups is removed.

For now I only figured out how to select the last group, but it also selects the `_`:

```
(?:.(?!(?=\_)))+$
```

**Note 2:** I am currently focusing on the regex part but it is a code to be used in R if it helps to get to a solution.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use regex? To me, using `strsplit` on `'_'` followed by `paste(..., collapse = '_')` seems like an easier solution to solve this particular example.

Comment: So simple... 3 hours that I am looking at the problem the wrong way. Thanks !
I am still curious however to learn more about regex so if anyone has the answer :)

Comment: Well, there can be a regex-based answer with matching the groups, like [`^(.*?)_((?:_?[^_]+){3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/rW0sE8/1). Replace the number inside `{...}` to get the parts you need. Just when you use a number outside of the range the behavior might become weird.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will never have to get to a number that does not match the number of `_` as I proceed step by step until the first group matches a certain value but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility to split on the nth occurrence of `_` from the end of the string:

```
strsplit("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "_(?=([^_]*_){0}[^_]*$)", perl = T)
                                     #    ^
                                     #  you can modify the quantifier here
#[[1]]                                         
#[1] "abc_def_ghi" "jkl"                    # split on the 1st

strsplit("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "_(?=([^_]*_){1}[^_]*$)", perl = T)
#[[1]]
#[1] "abc_def" "ghi_jkl"                    # split on the 2nd

strsplit("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "_(?=([^_]*_){2}[^_]*$)", perl = T)
#[[1]]
#[1] "abc"         "def_ghi_jkl"            # split on the 3rd
```

`_(?=([^_]*_){2}[^_]*$)` looks for `_` before the pattern `([^_]*_){2}[^_]*$` via `?=` look ahead syntax and the pattern starts from the end of the string `$` and skips any non `_` patterns `[^_]*` and matches `([^_]*_)` for certain number of occurrences and after that split on the specified `_`.

*Update* with `str_match` from `stringr` package:

```
str_match("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "(.*)_((?:[^_]*_){0}[^_]*$)")[,2:3]
# [1] "abc_def_ghi" "jkl"     

str_match("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "(.*)_((?:[^_]*_){1}[^_]*$)")[,2:3]
# [1] "abc_def" "ghi_jkl"

str_match("abc_def_ghi_jkl", "(.*)_((?:[^_]*_){2}[^_]*$)")[,2:3]
# [1] "abc"         "def_ghi_jkl"
```